# List all groups of a user in Azure Active directory using the Azure API call

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

What is the Rest API for listing all groups in Azure Activedirectory from Spring boot application?

(at the moment a google search bring about the below two APIs which are as below, one is "Azure Active Directory Graph API" and another is "Azure API Management REST API Group entity"

Not sure which API exactly to use for getting list of groups of Azure AD ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to call the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) (though you can also do this with the Azure AD Graph API).

To [list all groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list?view=graph-rest-1.0), the request would be:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
```

In Java, you can use the [Microsoft Graph SDK for Java](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java), an example of how you could retrieve all groups (this includes paging through multiple pages of results, in case you have more than 999 groups):

```java
// Set up the Graph client
IGraphServiceClient graphClient = 
            GraphServiceClient
            .builder()
            .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .logger(new NotALogger())
            .buildClient();

// Set up the initial request builder and build request for the first page
IGroupCollectionRequestBuilder groupsRequestBuilder = graphClient.groups();
IGroupCollectionRequest groupsRequest = groupsRequestBuilder
    .buildRequest()
    .top(999);

do {
    try {
        // Execute the request
        IGroupCollectionPage groupsCollection = groupsRequest.get(); 

        // Process each of the items in the response
        for (Group group : groupsCollection.getCurrentPage()) {
            System.out.println(group.displayName);
        }

        // Build the request for the next page, if there is one
        groupsRequestBuilder = groupsCollection.getNextPage();
        if (groupsRequestBuilder == null) {
            groupsRequest = null;
        } else {
            groupsRequest = groupsRequestBuilder.buildRequest();
        }

    } catch(ClientException ex) {

        // Handle failure
        ex.printStackTrace();
        groupsRequest = null;
    }
} while (groupsRequest != null);
```

To [list all groups the signed-in user is a member of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0) (including nested groups):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/getMemberGroups
Content-type: application/json

{
  "securityEnabledOnly": true
}
```

Comment: Other Microsoft Graph Java clients are available: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-core